# Selenium error: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am extracting the first 'name' field on each page of the url: "http://www.srlworld.com/content/65/find-a-lab.html"

The for loop runs once and throws an error:

```
File "srl.py", line 40, in <module>
    print state.text
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 66, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 404, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8981)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmpPEHToH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8574)
    at WebElement.getElementText (file:///tmp/tmpPEHToH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11722)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpPEHToH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12282)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmpPEHToH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:603)
```

The code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.srlworld.com/content/65/find-a-lab.html")
#assert "http" in driver.title

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("country")
#driver.implicitly_wait(5)
all_countries = elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
country = all_countries[1]
print "country value is %s" % country.get_attribute("value")
country.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

state_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("state")
all_states = state_elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
del all_states[0]


for state in all_states:
    print "start ",
    print state.text

    print "state value is %s" % state.get_attribute("value")
    state.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    driver.find_element_by_name("go").click()

    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[span='Name'][1]/span/following-sibling::span[2]")
    print name.text
    print "end ",
    print state.text
```

On running this script, the for loop which runs only once doesn't print the last 'state.text' even though I am not making any changes.

Comment: What you want to display? state names in drop down..or any other?

Comment: Yeah state names as well as the first 'name' field that I am extracting using xpath. @SarithaG

Comment: try this xpath to get first name:  " .//*[@id='qname'] ".

Comment: I am getting the first name easily... there is no problem in that.. What I am not getting is that my code is not printing the next state i.e. 'Assam'

Comment: @SarithaG It prints this:     country value is INDIA
    start  ANDHRA PRADESH
    state value is ANDHRA PRADESH
    AMBICARE CLINICS & DIAGNOSTICS
    end 
    Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: There is no option tag na..Then how did u take option tag to find state_list??

Comment: Correct there is no option tag initially to find state list, hence to load the option tag into the html page I have written a piece where I click on the first country. After clicking the country, the state options load on the html page.

Comment: all_states = state_elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"); Is this working fine??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80380/discussion-between-aditya-and-saritha-g).

Comment: To me this happened when timeout ocurred..

Answer (score 1):

Considering the text of the exception, the following happens: each time you press the button "Go" the page refreshes itself (loads new data, not by AJAX, but by actually refreshing - this is important), therefore Selenium detects the page state change and throws an exception as you try to access elements from its previous state. I suggest the following algorithm to solve your problem:

```
current_position = 1

while True:
    try:
        state_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("state")
        all_states = state_elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
        state = all_states[current_position]
        print "start ",
        print state.text

        print "state value is %s" % state.get_attribute("value")
        state.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)

        driver.find_element_by_name("go").click()

        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[span='Name'][1]/span/following-sibling::span[2]")
        print name.text
        print "end ",
        print state.text
        current_position += 1
    except:
        break
```

This way, you select each time the next option on a freshly generated page, and you shouldn't get the exception you had before.

Comment: I am up-voting this because I believe in principle it is correct. However, would you say that the `break` belongs in the `try:` not the `except:`?